# Main Activity Relaunched on App Close

Tags: android, activity-lifecycle

I am making an android app on API 15 for a mobile computer application.
In this app I have a background service, a lot of classes inheriting from AsyncTask, and some sql updates and broadcasting to the service on the app pausing.

I have recently discovered an issue where going to a specific screen in my app, hitting the home button, bringing up my app list, and swiping away my app to kill it results in the app closing and then soon restarting itself at the main activity. It should just close normally.

I have tried placing breakpoints everywhere, and even disabling the background service, but i cannot seem to find any indication of what is restarting the app when it is closed.

I just tried getReferrer inside a try catch and my app says it isnt responding and shuts down even though its in a try catch block.

Both problem seem odd to me.

If it means anything, Android studio will still be debugging the app once it has opened again after i close it.

If anyone could shed some light on what could be restarting my app after i close it, it would be very helpful.

**EDIT:**

I am using Start_Not_Sticky. this and Start_Redeliver_Intent are ideal option from what i have read.

Comment: A sticky `Service` will restart several seconds after its app is swiped out of recents.  IIRC, this behavior has changed a couple times.  The service could then restart an activity.

Comment: I am returning Start_Not_Sticky, so nothing should be restarting.

Comment: Grep your code for references to your main activity class, or uses of `PackageManager` that might be looking up the launcher activity.

Comment: oh wow! Thank you, I had no idea i could `ctrl+shift+f` to search through all of my code instead of just a single activity at a time until you recommended grep. Thank you.
Once i saw all the references to it and threw breakpoints on it, it turned out that my current activity wasnt the one at fault, on destroy was being called on a an activity lower in my activity stack. 
the startactivity for my main page that was being hit was in the OnDestroy code.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to Kevin Krumwiede for suggesting grepping all my code for the main activity's name. I had no idea I could go through all of the code in my project within the IDE instead of going one file at a time.

I had previously tried going through all my classes and searching each individually for reference to it with `ctrl+f` but i never considered looking in one of my activities that i hadn't modified in months for the new issue.

when I used `ctrl+shift+f` it all came together as i saw the startActivity function inside of OnDestroy(), not sure how i never noticed this issue before.